# i cannot find where the database is called in sdk notepad sample project

Tags: database, project, sample, notepad

When I look at the notepad sample provided by the android SDK I see all of the database work is done in the notepaddataprovider class. I never see that class getting called so I don't understand how the database is getting created. I don't see an instance of that class anywhere. Can someone tell me what I am missing. I know it gets created because the project works when I run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the notepad provider is getting called in the manifest. It is listed under .

Comment: It is in the database provider.  I figured it out.